# Spring Integration Mail Google IMAP how to set the frequency of checking the inbox

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I have a working spring-mail-integration `(Spring boot application)` and can checks my google inbox.
I noticed by default that it is checking my inbox every 2 minutes.
I cannot remember any code that sets the time it checks my mail inbox.
Now, I am having an issue since there are times (rarely though) that my application cannot read from inbox..
I am just getting this in my log `attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]`
What I do to fix the issue is I restart my tomcat server, then my app can now check my email inbox again.

**Logs (with Date and time):**

```
2018-10-16 12:37:13 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 12:39:18 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 12:41:22 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 12:43:26 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 12:45:30 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 12:47:35 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 12:49:39 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 12:51:43 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 12:53:47 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 12:55:52 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 12:57:56 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:00:00 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:02:04 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:04:09 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:06:13 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:08:17 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:10:21 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:12:25 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:14:29 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:16:33 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:18:37 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:20:41 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:22:44 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:24:48 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:26:53 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:28:57 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:31:02 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:33:06 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:35:10 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:37:14 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:39:17 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:41:21 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:43:25 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:45:30 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:47:33 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
2018-10-16 13:49:38 - attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
```

**Question:**
1. How to change the time it checks the inbox?
2. Is two (2) minutes or lower a bad idea? I am thinking that google might ban the ip from accessing/checking the inbox.

**Dependency:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Mail Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    @SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
    @Qualifier(value = "javaMailSender")
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost(m_mailHost);
        mailSender.setPort(m_mailPort);
        mailSender.setUsername(m_mailUserEmail);
        mailSender.setPassword(m_mailPassword);
        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put(PROPERTY_MAIL_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL, m_mailProtocol);
        props.put(PROPERTY_MAIL_SMTP_AUTHENTICATION, m_mailSmtpAuth);
        props.put(PROPERTY_MAIL_SMTP_START_TLS_ENABLED, m_mailSmtpStartTlsEnabled);
        props.put(PROPERTY_MAIL_DEBUG, m_mailDebug);
        return mailSender;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value = "imapMailFlow")
    public IntegrationFlow imapMailFlow() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String user = URLEncoder.encode(mailUserEmail, ConstantUtil.CHARACTER_ENCODING);
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter("imaps://" + user + ":" + mailPassword + "@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox")
                        .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "false")
                                .put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory")
                                .put("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false").put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps"))
                        .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true).shouldDeleteMessages(false))
                .channel("receiveChannel").get();
    }

    ...

}
```

It would also be great if you could give a link regarding the explanations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `cancelIdleInterval`.

```
/**
 * IDLE commands will be terminated after this interval; useful in cases where a connection
 * might be silently dropped. A new IDLE will usually immediately be processed. Specified
 * in seconds; default 120 (2 minutes). RFC 2177 recommends an interval no larger than 29 minutes.
 * @param cancelIdleInterval the cancelIdleInterval to set
 * @since 3.0.5
 */
public void setCancelIdleInterval(long cancelIdleInterval) {
    this.cancelIdleInterval = cancelIdleInterval * 1000;
}
```

It is not currently exposed by the Java DSL so you will have to wire up an ImapMailReceiver as a bean.

**EDIT**

```
@Bean
public ImapMailReceiver receiver() {
    ImapMailReceiver receiver = new ImapMailReceiver("...some URL...");
    receiver.setCancelIdleInterval(300); // seconds
    receiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
    return receiver;

}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mailFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter(receiver()))
            // ...
            .get();
}
```

Comment: sorry if it is not clear to me.. when you say `wire up an ImapMailReceiver as a bean`, do you mean something like this `@Bean @Qualifier(value = "imapMailReceiver") public ImapMailReceiver getImapMailReceiver() { ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(); return imapMailReceiver; }`? But still I am not sure how to connect `ImapMailReceiver` to my `IntegrationFlow`

Comment: ic, i can set to something like `imapMailReceiver.setCancelIdleInterval(300000);` for 5 minutes. What is not clear to me now is how I can connect the `ImapMailReceiver` to `IntegrationFlow`

Comment: Simply pass it into the factory method - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I tried but I am getting an error 
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: An external 'receiver' [imaps://abc123%40gmail.com:xxxxxxxxxx@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox] can't be modified.`.
This is when calling `shouldMarkMessagesAsRead` and `shouldDeleteMessages` that calls `assertReceiver()`. If I remove the two, the application runs. Is there a way to call both `shouldMarkMessagesAsRead` and `shouldDeleteMessages` without getting the error?

Comment: I got it, I can set both `shouldMarkMessagesAsRead` and `shouldDeleteMessages` in ImapMailReceiver. I am not getting any errors now... I will check if the `cancelIdleInterval` is changed.

Comment: I tried setting `cancelIdleInterval` to `300000` but it seems it is still checking the inbox every 2 minutes. I was expecting that it will now check every 5 minutes (300 seconds).

Comment: I set the cancelIdleInterval value to seconds since in `setCancelIdleInterval()` it is multiplying the value set with 1000. Now it seems the value is applied but I am getting `javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` error. For the complete error log, please see https://pastebin.com/SELdyhMp. Thanks!

Comment: btw this is the complete log with mail debug: https://pastebin.com/dZFXdhvS

Comment: Its weird, if I set `cancelIdleInterval` to less than the default (2 minutes)... it works and it does not get the error (`FolderClosedException`). If I set it to something above 2 minutes (`120 seconds`)... I get the error. Now I get confused regarding `RFC 2177 recommends an interval no larger than 29 minutes.` if it only works if I set it to less than 2 minutes.

Comment: If cancelIdleInterval is set to 173 seconds and below... it can read the inbox every after 173 seconds... If I set it more than 173 seconds... it will have the error.. Kinda weird though

Comment: Yes; sorry; it's seconds. Looks like the mail server has a limit for the IDLE command and closes the connection if it's exceeded. I am guessing the original developer tested it with gmail and that's why he selected 120 seconds as the default :D

Comment: in that case I could not set the value greater than 173 seconds right? This is for google imap only I guess. Also, would it be possible that google will block or ban my tomcat server since 2 minutes checking of gmail inbox is too frequent? I ask because, there were times (rarely though) when it `attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]` but as if nothing happens... it is not able to read/receive new mails when it should be.

Comment: I have no idea; sorry; you would need to ask google.

Comment: @BorgyManotoy by any chance do you remember how you solved the `external 'receiver' ... can't be modified` error?

Comment: I am getting that error because I wrongly set `shouldMarkMessageAsRead` and `shouldDeleteMessages`. When I set it through `ImapMailReceiver`, I did not get the said error.