# How To Set Cancel-Idle-Interval Attribute of IMAP Mail Receiver Channel using XML Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to set the setCancelIdleInterval attribute of my imap idle receiving channel. I am using the xml based configuration. This is needed because of the issue reported here: "[Spring Integration Mail Google IMAP how to set the frequency of checking the inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832480/spring-integration-mail-google-imap-how-to-set-the-frequency-of-checking-the-inb)".

The solution given was for the Java DSL configuration and when I tried implementing it in xml, I got errors.

I read the Spring Integration documentation over again and tried to get a list of all the attributes supported by each receiving protocol (IMAP, POP3) but could not find any such documentation. If such a document could be made, it would be very helpful.

Below is imap-idle channel code that generates errors based on the cancel-idle-interval attribute.

```
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
        store-uri="imap://[username]:[password]@[domain]:993/INBOX"
        channel="receiveChannel"
        auto-startup="true"
        should-delete-messages="false"
        should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
        cancel-idle-interval=1740
        java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"/>
```

This is the error message I am getting when I tried to execute the project build:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [application-email-parser-config.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 66 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/application-email-parser-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 66; columnNumber: 52; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'cancel-idle-interval' is not allowed to appear in element 'int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:265) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:190) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:175) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:148) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:98) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4792) [catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256) [catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754) [catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730) [catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629) [catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839) [catalina.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_201]
```

Answer (score 0):

`cancelIdleInterval` is currently not configurable using XML; you have to wire up the bean using `JavaConfig` or use simple `<bean/>` configuration instead of the `int-mail:` namespace.

```xml
<bean id="receiver" class="org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver">
     <property name="cancelIdleInterval" value="30" />
     ... other properties.
</bean>

<bean id="adapter" class="org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter">
    <constructor-arg ref="receiver" />
    ... other properties (outputChannel etc).
</bean>
```

I opened [an issue to add it to the `int-mail` namespace](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3017).

Comment: Thanks Gary, I will play with this now.

Also, can the team create a document with all the attributes that can be used in the receiving channels? It will be very helpful.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: You can look at the XSD (schema) to see which attributes are supported; if you use an IDE that is Spring-aware (STS, IDEA etc), you can get content-assist for valid properties when creating XML configuration.